# C++ threadpool / executor implementation

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++14

Yes, yes, I know, another threadpool implementation - but I didn't see any implementations that had quite what I wanted. That is, using modern features such as `std::future` and `std::packaged_task` to be able to simply enqueue tasks and wait for their result. I have been very unimpressed by `std::async` because (at least with gcc) it spawns a new thread for each function, which is very inefficient for small functions.

You create an instance of this somewhere, then call `run` with a function - `run` returns a `future` that will contain the function's return value (or exception thrown) once you wait for it.

```
#include <thread>
#include <queue>
#include <mutex>
#include <condition_variable>
#include <future>

class ThreadPool {
    public:
    ThreadPool(unsigned num_threads = std::thread::hardware_concurrency()) {
        while (num_threads--) {
            threads.emplace_back([this] {
                while(true) {
                    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(mutex);
                    condvar.wait(lock, [this] {return !queue.empty();});
                    auto task = std::move(queue.front());
                    if (task.valid()) {
                        queue.pop();
                        lock.unlock();
                        // run the task - this cannot throw; any exception
                        // will be stored in the corresponding future
                        task();
                    } else {
                        // an empty task is used to signal end of stream
                        // don't pop it off the top; all threads need to see it
                        break;
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }

    template<typename F, typename R = std::result_of_t<F&&()>>
    std::future<R> run(F&& f) const {
        auto task = std::packaged_task<R()>(std::forward<F>(f));
        auto future = task.get_future();
        {
            std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(mutex);
            // conversion to packaged_task<void()> erases the return type
            // so it can be stored in the queue. the future will still
            // contain the correct type
            queue.push(std::packaged_task<void()>(std::move(task)));
        }
        condvar.notify_one();
        return future;
    }

    ~ThreadPool() {
        // push a single empty task onto the queue and notify all threads,
        // then wait for them to terminate
        {
            std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(mutex);
            queue.push({});
        }
        condvar.notify_all();
        for (auto& thread : threads) {
            thread.join();
        }
    }

    private:
    std::vector<std::thread> threads;
    mutable std::queue<std::packaged_task<void()>> queue;
    mutable std::mutex mutex;
    mutable std::condition_variable condvar;
};
```

You would use this class like so:

```
#include <iostream>

#include <ThreadPool.h>

int main() {
    ThreadPool pool;
    std::vector<std::future<int>> futures;
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
        futures.emplace_back(pool.run([i] {return i;}));
    }
    for (int i = 990; i < 1000; i++) {
        // prints 990...999
        std::cout << futures[i].get() << std::endl;
    }
}
```

All the threads should get joined on destruction of the `ThreadPool` object and they should exit cleanly. It shouldn't matter if the futures are destructed first or not. It should work with non-copyable return types.

I am looking for feedback because I know this kind of concurrent code is easy to screw up - I think I have everything right (exception safe, data race-free etc.).

---

Preempting a particular comment that might come up:

I am using `mutable` fields because I want the `const` qualifier to apply to the `run` function. I think this because it should be safe to call `run` from 2 different threads concurrently, which I think of as each thread only having immutable access to the `ThreadPool` (const reference). The `const` tells me that no internals of the `ThreadPool` that are not locked by a mutex should change when I call the function. If this sounds loony, let me know (I'm coming from Rust where this is the standard way to do things).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I am using mutable fields because I want the const qualifier to apply to the run function...

Considering every single member is mutable save for the thread pool itself, I find that a very poor justification for injecting a pretty severe code smell.

**Edit** Specifically, it's not like your class has parts of its public interface that are not thread-safe, in which case, you could maybe have an argument.

That being said, a few quibbles:

- I find usage of `unsigned` pretty iffy. I would explicitely use `unsigned int`.
- MSVC refuses to compile your code because `queue.push(std::packaged_task<void()>(std::move(task)));` "somehow" invokes `std::packaged_task<>`'s copy constructor. GCC and clang are fine. Seems to be MSVC's fault, but something to keep in mind.
- On that subject, you should use `queue.emplace()` instead of `queue.push()`
- Not popping off the empty task seems a bit fragile to me. I'd rather push as many empty tasks as there are threads, and let the regular logic handle that instead of special-casing it.

Like this:

```
auto task = std::move(queue.front());
queue.pop();
lock.unlock();

// invalid task signals shutdown.
if(!task.valid()) {
  break;
}
// run the task - this cannot throw; any exception
// will be stored in the corresponding future
task();
```

Other than that, this looks reasonable to me.